# How to split complex string in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, split

I have a string of parameters from a Javascript function call

```
ITQPopup('100',255,'2932 NTYwNDUwMTA0MDYzMDM);3094 V0FZ','-1909432577',0,0)
```

As you can see, this is very poorly coded, there are 6 parameters being passed

```
'100'
255
'2932 NTYwNDUwMTA0MDYzMDM);3094 V0FZ'
'-1909432577'
0 
0
```

I would split the string by "," (comma) but I'm afraid there could be commas in the 3rd parameter. How would one go about splitting this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with RegEx.  For instance:

```
Dim input As String = "ITQPopup('100',255,'2932 NTYwNDUwMTA0MDYzMDM);3094 V0FZ','-1909432577',0,0)"
Dim pattern As String = "ITQPopup\('(.*?)',(.*?),'(.*?)','(.*?)',(.*?),(.*?)\)"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
If m.Success Then
    Dim param1 As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Dim param2 As String = m.Groups(2).Value
    Dim param3 As String = m.Groups(3).Value
    Dim param4 As String = m.Groups(4).Value
    Dim param5 As String = m.Groups(5).Value
    Dim param6 As String = m.Groups(6).Value
End If
```

You could further improve the pattern, if necessary, to allow white-space between parameters, etc.  But that's the simplest working example.

Comment: I created this RegEx pattern `\('([0-9]*?)',([0-9]*?),'(.*?)','(-[0-9]*?)',([0-9]*?),([0-9]*?)\)` is this more specific?

Comment: Yes, that is better.  It still doesn't handle white-space between parameters, but it limits the numeric ones to only be numeric digits.  Instead of `[0-9]`, you could just use `\d`.  You may also want to allow an optional negative sign on each numeric parameter.  For instance: `(-?\d*?)`.  Also, including the negative sign inside the grouping would be helpful.

Comment: the only whitespaces I see are in the 3rd parameter, but `.` should match everything correct?

Comment: Yes.  `.` will match whitespace.  I just meant that the pattern wouldn't work if there were spaces *between* the parameters, for instance: `'100',   255,   "`

Comment: For some reason this `\('(-?\d*?)'.*?,.*?(-?\d*?).*?,.*?'(.*?)'.*?,.*?'(-?\d*?)'.*?,.*?(-?\d*?).*?,.*‌​?(-?\d*?)\)` doesn't match 255 and the first 0, any ideas? (resolved by taking `.*?` out from the end of each group...) the whitespace if any, would probably be in the beginning of the parameter right?

Answer (score 2):

Strip the content of the brackets, wrap in the square brackets and use JSON library to parse it as array.

Comment: I'm sure this is a great way to go as well, but I prefer regex (as the rest of my project uses it a lot) so I don't have to reference anything else as a dependency. Thanks Karel

Answer (score 1):

You can use Split.

Then to retrieve your parameters, you just have to take the 2 first elements of your list as your 1st 2 parameters.

Then do the same for the last 3 parameters.

Then all the remaining can be concatenated to give your 3rd parameter.

Comment: I thought about that but I wanted an easier answer, either RegEx, or another form of achieving this